# Ember Simple Auth login errors not displaying on page

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am following an online video tutorial that has setting up Ember Simple Auth Login. Everything works with exception to displaying login errors (i.e., 401 unauthorized) to the template. I have checked the code for typos but cannot find any.

In the controller login, I tried logging the `e.errors` to the console, but the console just says 'Undefined'. Though, if I just send the error object `e` to the log then I get the error object with the `error.detail` inside of it. Note: the `error.detail` is what I am trying to display on the login-form.hsb.

Any help is appreciated!

- Ember             : 3.4.5
- Ember Data        : 3.4.2
- jQuery            : 3.3.1
- Ember Simple Auth : 1.7.0

**Controllers/login.js**

```
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
    session: service('session'),

    actions: {
        login(attrs) {
            this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:jwt', {
                email: attrs.email,
                password: attrs.password
            }).then(() => {
                this.transitionToRoute('index');
            }).catch((e) => {
                this.set('errors', e.errors); // nothing is being displayed
                console.log(e.errors); // Says Undefined in the console
                console.log(e); // Display error to console
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**templates/login.hsb**

```
{{login-form user=model errors=errors onsubmit=(action "login")}}
```

**templates/components/login-form.hbs**

```
<div class="slide-out">
    <div class="slide-out-card">
        <div class="slide-out-heading">
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Login</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slide-out-content">
            <form onsubmit={{action "login"}}>
                <!-- this does not display the error message -->
                {{#each errors as |error|}}
                    {{error.detail}}
                    <div class="error-alert">{{error.detail}}</div>
                {{/each}}
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    {{input type="text" placeholder="Email" value=email}}
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    {{input type="password" placeholder="Password" value=password}}
                </div>

                <div class="form-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was received from Embercasts. There is a breaking change in Simple Auth. The code should now be `e.json.errors`

```
export default Controller.extend({
    session: service('session'),

    actions: {
        login(attrs) {
            this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:jwt', {
                email: attrs.email,
                password: attrs.password
            }).then(() => {
                this.transitionToRoute('index');
            }).catch((e) => {
                this.set('errors', e.json.errors); // Breaking change to Simple Auth - should be e.json.errors, instead of e.errors
            });
        }
    }
});
```